# How to integrate wordpress blog into my site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website using HTML & bootstrap and I want to add my blog to this site. I want to keep all my design the way it is, including my navigation. I don't want users to go to my WordPress page. Instead, I just want to integrate the blog part (adding the full blog from WP into my site).

My understanding is that I need to use the Loop to integrate it, but I am having trouble. Can someone please help me? Currently, I'm using the code below, but it cuts off each blog from the beginning and it's not showing the full posts:

```
<?php require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');?>
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>    
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

There must be a way to show my full blog posts on my site. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: its not a simple modification . better hire a developer .

Comment: There is a Wordpress plugin that gives access to blog posts via a REST API: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: It was actually very simple. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out after reading and reading lol.. here's the solution. It was very simple.
All I needed was to replace:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>  with the content  <?php the_content(); ?>
```